# Update elementor page from Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I'm having problems updating my Wordpress pages from the Wordpress API.

Currently I have pages created and edited with Gutenberg which I can edit from Postman by calling the API
Wordpress

https://example/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/100 and passing a content as a parameter updates the entire page.

The problem is that if I edit any of these pages with Elementor and invoke it again from Postman, it is no longer updated at any time.

I don't have caching plugins and I have the free version of Elementor.

Does anyone know if any additional parameters need to be passed in the call or if some type of adjustment needs to be made so that the pages modified or created with Elementor refresh the changes made from the Wordpress API?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new page you can use the WP API (POST [/wp/v2/pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#create-a-page)) and include the "template" field as described in the docs I sent you.

Elementor stores the page content, settings, CSS, ...etc in the wp_postmeta table as JSON. To update the page all you need to do is set up a custom API endpoint that updates the wp_postmeta table's meta_value column using the post_id from the first request and the appropriate meta_key for whichever parts of the [Elementor JSON](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/data-structure/) data you require. Here are some examples of various meta_key values you will likely want to include: _elementor_content, _elementor_settings, _elementor_css, ...etc) in the request body.

You could use the [wpdb::update_db method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) to select and update the right row.

Later, if needed, you can update any page using the same endpoint without ever needing to import the new version of the template or manually updating the page. Just fetch the required Elementor JSON from wp_postmeta and send another request to the same endpoint.

Here is an example of an custom REST endpoint allowing you to update the Elementor JSON in the postmeta table. Make sure to setup the auth callback or anyone could set your page's content to whatever they like.

```
// Register the custom endpoint
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'your-namespace/v1', '/update-elementor-content', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'update_elementor_content',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true', // Adjust permission check as needed
  ));
});

// Callback function for the endpoint
function update_elementor_content( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $post_id = $request->get_param( 'post_id' );
  $meta_key = $request->get_param( 'meta_key' );
  $meta_value = $request->get_param( 'meta_value' );

  // Validate data
  if ( empty( $post_id ) || empty( $meta_key ) || empty( $meta_value ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'missing_data', 'Please provide all required data (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)', 400 );
  }

  global $wpdb;

  // Update wp_postmeta table
  $result = $wpdb->update( 
      $wpdb->postmeta, 
      array( 'meta_value' => $meta_value ), 
      array( 'post_id' => $post_id, 'meta_key' => $meta_key ) 
  );

  if ( $result === false ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'update_failed', 'Failed to update Elementor content', 500 );
  }

  // Success response
  return array(
    'message' => 'Elementor content updated successfully',
  );
}
```